# Crystal Reports - use formula for parameter alternative

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, report, formula

I have a report that shows some statistics for the previous day. Typically this is the previous day (dateadd("d", -1, CurrentDate)) but if it is Monday (dayOfWeek=2), I need it to use the previous three days (dateadd("d", -3, CurrentDate)) . I know how to do this, but I need these values to be defaults of the parameter, and be able to have the user be able to change this dates.  From what I can tell, you cant set the default value of a parameter to a variable. How else could I accomplish this??

Answer (score 0):

Your formula should be based on your variable. You also can have a global variable inside Crystal.
I dont have the crystal right now, but a code example would be:

```
numbervar myVariable := {?yourParameter};
(dateadd("d", -myVariable, CurrentDate))
```

Comment: I changed your formula to valid Crystal syntax. This would require the end user to select the date by knowing how many days in the past the date they're looking for was and also doesn't address default parameter values or the required Monday logic.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make your date parameter optional (available in CR 2008 and higher versions). If no value is selected by the end user then use the logic you described, otherwise, use the date they selected. Example of this logic in the report's record selection formula:

```
if hasvalue({?DateParameter}) then {table.field}={?DateParameter}
else 
  if dayofweek(currentdate)=2 then //today is Monday
    {table.field} in dateadd("d",-3,currentdate) to dateadd("d",-1,currentdate)
  else {table.field}=dateadd("d",-1,currentdate)
```